# Can a mobile app (not native app!) be forced portrait or landscape?

Tags: mobile-web

My client wants his mobile app (not a native iPhone/Android app) to be portrait only. Can this be forced by HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: This is not actually a UX question. It's more of a 'how do I do this technical thing' - so nothing related to improving the users experience as such.

Comment: If you question is "can" not "should" I think this is a Stack Overflow question

Comment: "Should" is a moot point, because you can't force it... you can only force different stylesheets.  Now, there is a legitimate UX discussion to be had around what the differences between stylesheets should be, if bart cares to edit his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iPhone, at least, this question has already been answered on StackOverflow: [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application).  The short answer is no, but that you can supply different CSS styles for each orientation, so that you can make it functional for both cases.

I'd be interested if there are any differences for Android/WP7/BB, if anyone knows, though.